# want to show text in placeholder optional using php

Tags: php

i have textbox i want to show value in it optionally, either if $searchText contain data so show it if it is empty so show text. how to do?? i have tried several code

Thanks

```
         <input type="text" name="search_text" value="<?php
if($_REQUEST['search_text'] = !"")
  {
  echo "string";
}
else{
       echo $searchText;
}


       ?>">
```

Comment: `= !""` ? Where in the PHP manual is this syntax taught? Your haphazard formatting further indicates a lack of attention to detail.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit i have tried this code, i do not know it is ok or not. kindly you suggest any code

Comment: You know ther is a html placeholder attribut? See: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp

Comment: @Rizier123 see my code first

Comment: `<input type="text" placeholder="Your Search String" name="search_text" value="<?=(isset($_REQUEST['search_text']) && $_REQUEST['search_text']) ? $_REQUEST['search_text'] : 'string'?>">`

Comment: @PleaseWait why did not you post your answer?

Comment: @MuhammadSubhanKhan If you have 4 answers on your question and non of the are right for you,then  i think you have to specify your question what exactly you want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all guys to help me finally this is the answer

```
<input type="text" name="search_text" class="top_search_box" value="<?php 
if( isset($_REQUEST['search_text']))
  { echo $_REQUEST['search_text'];}
else{
   echo 'search...' ; 
}
?>" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are checking if a request has been made to this page but if not, or if empty, display placeholder text...

```
<input type="text" name="search_text" <?php if(!empty($_REQUEST['search_text'])) echo 'value="'.htmlentities($_REQUEST['search_text'], ENT_QUOTES),'"'; ?> placeholder="<?php echo $searchText; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your looking for something link this:

(The Text is only visible if nothing is written in the textbox!)

```
<input type="text" name="search_text" placeholder="Im a placeholder" >
```

See link for placeholder attribute and how god implemented it is:

[Placeholder Attribute](http://w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp)

[Implementation in Browser's](http://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you like below

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Your Search String" name="search_text" value="<?=(isset($_REQUEST['search_text']) && $_REQUEST['search_text']) ? $_REQUEST['search_text'] : 'string'?>">
```